# Https force redirect is not working properly... All search pages are not redirecting on https

Tags: https

I have bought SSL certificate from Namecheap and installed on Hostgator c-panel. Some organic search traffic pages are not redirecting on https. Https is not showing in Google Search. My .htaccess file is like as

```
# Use PHP55
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php55 .php
<IfModule mod_suphp.c>
suPHP_ConfigPath /opt/php55/lib
</IfModule>


# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
# Always use https for secure connections
# Replace 'www.mydomain.in' with your domain name
# (as it appears on your SSL certificate)
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mydomain.in/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Silly question but did you replace `mydomain.in` to your domain? and can you confirm that within WordPress you have changed the site address from HTTP to HTTPS?

Comment: i have done this replacement  but it is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will obviously need to make sure you have done the two things that @Simon mentioned in comments. Namely to use your actual domain in the `RewriteRule` directive and to change the WordPress/Site address in the admin section.

However, you have put your redirect code in `.htaccess` in the wrong place! This is a show stopper. By placing the mod_rewrite directives at the end of the file, after the WordPress front-controller, they will never get executed (at least not for any WordPress URLs). So, the code you posted won't actually be doing anything!

You need to place the redirect code *before* the WordPress front-controller. ie. *Before* the `# BEGIN WordPress` section.

Comment: Thank you so much. I have done and now it is working nicely.